# Sorting OrderedDict from Csvfile

Tags: python, csv

I've been trying to sort an `OrderedDict` which I fetch from a csv file but it always gives me the error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong and Google searching gave me no answer.

My code is:

```
def exsort(filen):
dic={}
with open(filen) as excel:
    rdr = csv.reader(excel)
    next(excel)
    for cell in rdr:
        dic[cell[0]] = float(cell[1]), float(cell[2])
return OrderedDict(sorted(rdr, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

The values of the csv file are:

```
['Alison', '100', '0']
['Bart', '100', '5']
['Claris', '100', '10']
['Danny', '90', '0']
['Evelyn', '90', '5']
```

And I basically want to print an `OrderedDict` sorted out by the name.

Comment: you are trying to call `rdr` outside of your `with` block, which automatically calls all necessary exit protocols for your file object.

Comment: I just tried un-indenting my return statement and it gave me this:
"OrderedDict()" just that. Any

Comment: thats because your `rdr` is at the end of your file, you would have to do something like `excel.seek(0)` but because you are dealing with an excel reader, I am not sure if that is allowed. I would instead do something like [the sorted by keys](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) example in this link

Comment: Thank you! I finally understood what I was doing wrong! I can't seem to be able to mark your answer as the correct one though.

Comment: Will post as an answer, give me a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to call on `rdr` outside the scope of your `with` block, which automatically calls `exit` protocols on your file object (including something along the lines of `file.close()`. You obviously can't deal with closed files, thus the error.

However, there are also a few things you should keep in mind:

1. Just moving the `return` to inside the `with` block will not work because `rdr` is a file-like object which means iterating through it will move your file cursor to the end. I am not quite sure if doing something like `excel.seek(0)` (which would normally move a file objects cursor back to the start of the file) would work in this case because you are using `csv.reader`
2. This is unnecessary anyways because it seems that you can just do something like the `sort by keys` example in [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes)